# Regex extracting numeric & alpha separately

Tags: regex

Fairly new to this, but I have the following type of data string:

RT-2125.00INR/CF-MATEY

I need to extract the value (2125.00) & the currency Code (INR), the initial part is a currency value so it might or might not have a decimal point and will be a variable length but will always be a positive value.

```
RT-(?<RateAmount>.*)/CF-
```

gives me 2125.00INR

I've tried `RT-(?<RateAmount>\d.*)/CF-` & `RT-(?<RateAmount>[0-9].*)/CF-` but they still return the same & `RT-(?<RateAmount>[0-9]+.*?<Currency>[A-Z]+.*)/CF-` just doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
RT-(?<RateAmount>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?<Currency>[A-Z]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Abvx0K/1)

[image]

**Details**

- `RT-` - an `RT-` literal substring
- `(?<RateAmount>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group "RateAmount": 1 or more digits optionally followed with `.` and 1+ digits
- `(?<Currency>[A-Z]+)` - Group "Currency": 1+ uppercase ASCII letters.

Answer (score 0):

You need character classes (I'm pretty sure there are a couple of duplicates though):

```
RT-(?<RateAmount>[\d.]+)(?<Currency>[A-Z]+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ESmxiB/1).

Comment: That's going to allow `RT-12.34.56ABC` which should be invalid as it has two `.` characters